# Getting 403 Forbidden error when trying to access Dockerized service locally after exposing ports

Tags: docker, containers, export, port, ngrx

I am currently running a script within a Docker environment and attempting to access the service locally after exposing ports using Docker. However, when I try to access the service via the exposed port in my local browser, I receive a 403 Forbidden error.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Started a Docker container with the necessary service running inside.
2. Exposed the required port using the **`-p`** flag when running the Docker container, for example: **`docker run -d -p 8080:80 <image_id>`**.

Despite following these steps, I'm consistently encountering the 403 Forbidden error when trying to access the service via **`http://localhost:8080/`** in my local browser.

Could someone please provide guidance on what might be causing this issue and how I can resolve it? Are there any specific configurations or settings I need to adjust within my Docker environment?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you are getting an HTTP 403 error and not something like a "connection refused" message, then the Docker-level setup is correct and your application is failing the connection.  The `docker run` command on its own seems fine; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: @ as iam new to docker can u plz help me how to over come this error in detail

Comment: There's not enough information in the question to really say more.

Answer (score 0):

403 suggest you are reaching your service, check logs of your service.

Similar example:

```bash
docker run -d --rm -p 80:80 --name nginx nginx
curl 127.0.0.1
```

results in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

If you started your container with name, and your service logs to stdout/stderr, you can check logs like below (my container name was set to `nginx`):

```
docker logs -f nginx
```

Comment: as iam new to docker can you please guide me how to overcome this error

Comment: what's the image you are trying to run?

Comment: @ 
Greg0ry iam trying to run gstream image

Comment: I can't see `gstream` image in dockerhub, what is the image ID you used when running `docker pull`?